# Why are the frameSwapped and aboutToCompose signals of QOpenGLWidget emitted almost simultaneously?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-3

In theory, if I enable the vertical sync option with setSwapInterval(1), the time interval between the emissions of these two signals should be at least the refresh period of the display. However, in practice, I find that the moments when these two signals are emitted are almost simultaneous in my environment. Why is this? Have I overlooked any settings options? This makes me feel as if the step of swapping the buffer has not taken place.

This is my options:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setVersion(3, 3);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
format.setSwapInterval(1);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
......
```

Qt:5.12.10
Windows10 SDK

Comment: Why do you think that it `should be at least the refresh period of the display"? With v-sync I expect the system to time the swap and the compose as close as possible to reduce the latency.

Comment: Oh, do you expect that both your app and the compositor synchronize with the monitor? I'm pretty sure that is not the case. I don't know the gory details, but I'd expect the compositor to synchronize with the monitor; however your app renders to the off-screen buffer that the compositor reads from rather than the monitor, so it's synchronizing with the compositor rather than the monitor. Basically the implementation is more clever than you assumed, in order to reduce that one frame latency.

Comment: Actually, I want to calculate the actual rendering time of a frame. I saw that QT has similar signals, and the information I read from the documentation led me to believe that it does indeed work that way. If that's the case, the time difference between these two signals seems to be the actual rendering time. @Yakov Galka

Comment: I don't think it will give you any meaningful measurement. You're simply assuming too much about the implementation. To measure the time it takes to render the frame, you shall use the [`GL_TIME_ELAPSED` query](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object).